# Cannot set cookie from backend express api to frontend next(react) app - both on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, fetch

Currently I am trying to save a JWT token in the clients cookies after a login fetch. When looking at the set-cookie response in the Network tab of dev tools I get `This set cookie was blocked because its domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url.`

[image: cookie set response]

This is the code I use to set the cookie:

```
const token = user.generateVerificationToken();
const cookieOptions = {
    domain: 'http://dev.com:3000',
    // expires: new Date(Date.now() + 60000),
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 30 days
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: req.secure || req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https',
};
  
res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);
```

These are the cors settings:

```
app.use( cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://dev.com:3000'}) );
```

This is what the fetch request looks like on the client:

```
let res = await fetch( 'http://api.dev.com:4000/login', {
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // login data
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include'
    })
```

`/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 dev.com
127.0.0.1 api.dev.com
```

Can anyone help with this? I can't find what needs to be done to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with CORS. Instead, this is a problem with cookies (cross-domain issue).

You're trying to set a cookie for `dev.com:3000`, but the API is located on `api.dev.com:4000`. It is cross-domain and cross-origin, and because of that, it is invalid cookie.

If I recall correctly, it is impossible for you to set cookies to a different domain. If such things were possible, it would be a serious security issue.

So, there are two possible solutions to your problem:

- If you really want to set cookie for `dev.com:3000`, the workaround that will work is to provide the cookie value as a `res` object from your API, and then **in the front-end**, you turn that `res` into a cookie. You can use various JavaScript's APIs or plugins for that, such as `document.cookie`, `react-cookie`, `universal-cookie`, `js-cookie`, and many more.
- **If you ask for my opinion**, just turn that `api.dev.com:4000` to `api.dev.com:3000`, or run them in the same port. It is possible to send cookies **from the same domain origin**.
- I noticed that you're using Next.js. You can use the serverless API to receive the cookie from your backend (you still have to send the cookie via `res` too), then set the cookie using the serverless API. As the serverless API and the frontend are located in the same `4000` port, the cookie should be valid. This way, you can preserve the `httpOnly` attribute of the cookie.

For further reference, refer to my answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66595631/not-able-to-receive-set-cookies-in-browser-from-backend-in-mern-app-with-backend/66596364#66596364).

Comment: Thank this really helps clear things up. Where you say 'change api.dev.com:4000 to api.dev.com:3000' how do I go about doing this on a local environment. Because in production they'll be on the same port (different servers, same domain), but with local development how do I go about this. Do I need to edit this in /etc/hosts, do I need to proxy requests, or something else?

Comment: I thought you're using `api.dev.com` in the development? It should be possible to change the port if you're using different subdomains. If you're using `localhost` however, you just set the `origin` to `*`. Don't forget to change it in production.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, please mark it as accepted. Thanks.