# Browser ignores Set-Cookie from backend server

Tags: cookies, axios, cors, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, dj-rest-auth

This has been asked [countless times](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=axios+response+set-cookie+not+saving), yet I am unable to find a solution that works.

When using Axios I found that it (Chrome/the browser) appears to ignore `Set-Cookie` headers under some circumstances. I am working with a Django backend running `django-cors-headers`, `djangorestframework`, `djangorestframework-simplejwt`, and `dj-rest-auth` - a fairly typical collection of tooling.

My cross-origin architecture:

```
React-based frontend: http://127.0.0.1:3000
Django backend: http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

While building authentication I noticed that my browser is not properly saving cookies that are provided by my backend. For instance,

Preflight `OPTIONS` response

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: accept, authorization, content-type, user-agent, x-csrftoken, x-requested-with
access-control-allow-methods: DELETE, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
access-control-allow-origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000
access-control-max-age: 86400
content-length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 25 Jul 2023 18:58:48 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.11.3
Vary: origin
```

Follow-up response (to authentication with backend)

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 351
Content-Type: application/json
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Date: Tue, 25 Jul 2023 18:58:48 GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.11.3
Set-Cookie:  auth=XXXXX; expires=Tue, 25 Jul 2023 18:54:44 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=300; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
```

I can see the cookie in the response, but the browser does not *save* the cookie into its data store. Nor does it present any warning for why it may be ignoring them. I did find under other circumstances that it would display a small yellow triangle citing a SAMESITE issue, but I am not seeing this now.

---

I do send axios requests to the backend as

```
axios.put(URL, data, {withCredentials:true});
```

and have my backend configured with

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Otherwise the browser will reject the attempt to send the request at all per the response it received from the preflight `OPTIONS` request. And anyway, my understanding of `withCredentials` was so that the browser would send along any site data (e.g. cookies) it had stored for the domain. But in this case, the issue appears to be in the initial storing of those data.

I tried to adjust which headers were "exposed" to the frontend by trying these (separately, first just `Set-Cookie` then "everything" as a hammer-tactic).

```
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = ['Set-Cookie'];
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = ['*']
```

but the behavior remained the same.

So all this *seems* to work as far as I can see ... just the browser is opting to ignore any cookies sent to it by the backend and I'm not sure how to debug this.

I feel a if there is a CORS/SAMESITE/? issue lurking here and I just lack the experience to track it down.

EDIT: Sounds like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66619365/cannot-set-cookie-from-backend-express-api-to-frontend-nextreact-app-both-on) may be relevant here, too.

Comment: I think the issue is well defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412839/2446071). It's a wonder what knowledge is lost amongst developers these days when frameworks manage all the hard stuff for you.